# Bounced emails with email on Google Apps for Business

Tags: email

I use Google Apps for Business.

I have things set so I can login at gmail.com using richard(at)wordfruit.com as my login name, and when I send mail it sends from richard(at)wordfruit.com

I've had a couple of people tell me that emails bounced. From lots of other people I've received emails fine.

People who got bounced emails have contacted me through a contact form on wordfruit.com -- messages through that form get delivered to richard(at)wordfruit.com (the same email that those people got bounces with).

One person who got a bounce tried emailing me again later and got a bounce again. Both times, that person was able to contact me through the online form.

Where should I look to solve this? Or how can I solve it?

Here's a message that one person got:

Message: Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently: Richard(at)wordfruit.com Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 535 535 Incorrect authentication data (SMTP AUTH failed with the remote server) (state 7).

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the MX records set up correctly. Even if you added googles MX records, make sure you also delete any default ones that your domain name or hosting company have created. Here are the instructions from [google](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&safe=on&answer=140034).

Comment: It won't also hurt to SPF records too.

Comment: Great tip @ionFish here is more info http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786